# Should running preg_replace twice break a WAMP connection?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, wamp

I am trying to replace some text in a string using `preg_replace`. Now, maybe I am not doing it correctly, but running it once, doesn't do the trick as I am trying to replace overlapping strings. Now when I run `preg_replace` once, it works fine (minus only half of the text is the way I want). When I try to run it twice I get a bad connection error in both Chrome and IE (so it isn't a browser issue, not that I thought it would be) at least for WAMP (I haven't tried it on a real server).

So, is there something wrong with:

1) my PHP logic,

2) my regex,

3) or preg_replace and WAMP?

I want to separate (put spaces between) all of the numbers that have the following format: 0.xx

```
$text = "0.450.590.88 AUT 0.570.210.400.89 CUS 0.630.310.370.440.87 DEL 0.580.130.310.570.450.89 EVA 0.600.230.420.550.440.650.91 INT 0.590.390.620.530.540.520.560.85 IOP 0.480.240.440.440.440.550.580.600.88 MON 0.690.390.480.560.640.610.610.550.520.85"; 

for ($i=0;$i<2;$i++)
    $text = preg_replace('#0\.(\d{1,4})0\.#', '0.${1} 0.', $text);
```

I want $text to result in:

```
0.45 0.59 0.88 AUT 0.57 0.21 0.40 0.89 CUS 0.63 0.31 0.37 0.44 0.87 DEL 0.58 0.13 0.31 0.57 0.45 0.89 EVA 0.60 0.23 0.42 0.55 0.44 0.65 0.91 INT 0.59 0.39 0.62 0.53 0.54 0.52 0.56 0.85 IOP 0.48 0.24 0.44 0.44 0.44 0.55 0.58 0.60 0.88 MON 0.69 0.39 0.48 0.56 0.64 0.61 0.61 0.55 0.52 0.85
```

If I change the loop to run once or if I shorten the text, the PHP runs just fine.

As this is part of a larger text, I don't want to stick these into an array, I just want them formatted better. As a piece of background information this text comes from a correlation table in a PDF that has had the text extract, but the white space has not been preserved.

Comment: Works fine [here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/3VD6MY), maybe the error is somewhere else?

Comment: And what's the size of the sample that's crashing your server? The one you've posted shouldn't be able to crash a server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what is the relation between your preg_replace and your server crash, but you can do it in one step without a loop:

```
$result = preg_replace('~(?<=[0-9])(?=0\.[0-9]{1,4})~', ' ', $text);
```

Overlapping problems are avoided since the pattern only use lookarounds to determine the space position.